# Freeze while reading Bluetooth LE characteristics in C++Builder 11

Tags: windows, bluetooth, c++builder

I'm using Embarcadero C++Builder 11 Community Edition to write a simple program that connects to a selected Bluetooth LE device.

After discovering desired services, I try to read the characteristics, but the program hangs when reading the `service->Characteristics` property.

Here is my code snippet:

```cpp
TGUID VSP_GUID = StringToGUID("{569a1101-b87f-490c-92cb-11ba5ea5167c}");

void __fastcall TForm1::BluetoothLEServicesDiscovered(TObject * const Sender, TBluetoothGattServiceList * const AServiceList)
{
  for(int i=0;i<AServiceList->Count;i++)
  {
     if(AServiceList->Items[i]->UUID == VSP_GUID)
     {
       TBluetoothGattService * service = AServiceList->Items[i];

       if(service->Characteristics != NULL) //freezes here
       {
       }
     }
  }
}
```

The problem appears on Windows 11.  On Windows 10, everything worked fine.

Where is the problem?